# Why datetime in MATLAB is giving weird result?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to convert datenum values from double array. But conversion is leading to weird values in 'year'.

e.g.
     `t(1)=23823.1076388889;
      d=datetime(t,'ConvertFrom','datenum');
      d(1) = '22-Mar-0065 02:35:00'`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you trying to convert seconds to a more readable format?

Comment: The year should be 2015 instead of 0065. The time is in gregorian and it is basically  "days since 1950-01-01 00:00:00 UTC". So, what should I do such that it displays time as 22-Mar-2015 02:35:00.

Comment: In that case you have to convert the 1950-01-01 00:00:00 to a numeric value using datenum. add the result to your t(1) and then convert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB date numbers count the number of days since midnight, Jan 1<sup>st</sup> of the fictitious year 0 (counting backward from today using the Gregorian system with leap years).

You have a different offset, so you simply need to add that:

```
t  = 23823.1076388889;
t0 = datenum('1950-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
d  = datestr(t + t0)
```

which gives:

```
d =
    24-Mar-2015 02:35:00
```

Answer (score 3):

`23823.1076388889` is being interpreted as either a Julian date or a Proleptic Gregorian date with the decimal part being the proportion elapsed in that day.

`23823` is a day within the 65th year.

If you want to use a different scale, then use an additive constant. For example, to recover Excel-style dates after Feb 1900, you would need to add 2415019.

Comment: But the data says that time is in Gregorian format. I tried converting it to Julian but the result is same. So, I am not sure what's happening here. Also, the year should be 2015 technically. I got it that its the 65th year since 1950 but I need to have it in the array.

Comment: Which date where you expecting to get?

Answer (score 2):

You have to know which date format (the `'dateType'` argument) your `t(1)` is in. The `datenum` format gives the number of days since `0-Jan-0000`

23,000 days are around 63 years, so that explains your result.

Try the other formats listed here: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#inputarg_dateType